# PyObjC and method_exchangeImplementations: crash. correct usage?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, pyobjc, objective-c-runtime

I'm using PyObjC. PyObjC doesn't provide an interface to `method_exchangeImplementations` so I was trying to use the function via ctypes. I was trying to overwrite `windowShouldClose:` from some window controller class.

My code:

```
import objc
BrowserWindowController = objc.lookUpClass("BrowserWindowController")

class BrowserWindowController(objc.Category(BrowserWindowController)):
    def myWindowShouldClose_(self, sender):
        print "myWindowShouldClose", self, sender
        return self.myWindowShouldClose_(sender)

from ctypes import *
capi = pythonapi

# id objc_getClass(const char *name)
capi.objc_getClass.restype = c_void_p
capi.objc_getClass.argtypes = [c_char_p]

# SEL sel_registerName(const char *str)
capi.sel_registerName.restype = c_void_p
capi.sel_registerName.argtypes = [c_char_p]

def capi_get_selector(name):
    return c_void_p(capi.sel_registerName(name))

# Method class_getInstanceMethod(Class aClass, SEL aSelector)
# Will also search superclass for implementations.
capi.class_getInstanceMethod.restype = c_void_p
capi.class_getInstanceMethod.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p]

# void method_exchangeImplementations(Method m1, Method m2)
capi.method_exchangeImplementations.restype = None
capi.method_exchangeImplementations.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p]

def hook_into_close():
    clazz = capi.objc_getClass("BrowserWindowController")
    origClose = capi.class_getInstanceMethod(clazz, capi_get_selector("windowShouldClose:"))
    newClose = capi.class_getInstanceMethod(clazz, capi_get_selector("myWindowShouldClose:"))
    capi.method_exchangeImplementations(origClose, newClose)
```

This crashes. With some strange backtrace in `[NSWindow _close]`.

Is the code basically right?

What is the problem?

Comment: Is BrowserWindowController your class? If so, why are you exchanging its implementation for a different one rather than just doing what you need to do in its own implementation?

Comment: @Peter: No, it's coming from another framework where I cannot change the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, when I add `@objc.signature(BrowserWindowController.windowWillClose_.signature)` infront of `def myWindowShouldClose_`, it doesn't crash anymore.

So it just was the wrong/non-matching signature.